# Permission Denied Error when Using RSync to Copy Directory/Files from Ubuntu to RHEL Servers

Tags: rsync

I'm attempting to use rsync on a new RHEL server to copy files/directory from a remote Ubuntu server.  I used rsync -avx remote@host.com:/var/www/ /var/www/html

I'm then prompted for the password for remote@host.com and provide it.  Unfortunately, I receive permission denied (publickey,password).  Note that the username I'm using on the RHEL server is different from the username on the Ubuntu server.

How do I rectify this issue?

Thanks!!

Comment: type the correct password.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are having a problem with ssh, not with rsync that is trying to use ssh as a transport.  First get to the point where just `ssh remote@host.com` works, and work from there.  If you are being prompted for a password but you still cannot login, then either you have the wrong password (most likely), or there is some other problem.  If you are *certain* you have the correct password, then the best way to debug this is from the server side.  First check the server logs (/var/log/secure on RH).  If there is nothing useful there, my recommendation to debugging this beyond the password would be to run `/usr/sbin/sshd -d -p 2222` on the server to start a sshd in debug mode, then try `ssh -p 2222 remote@host.com` from the client side.  Then see what messages come out from the server when authentication fails.

Answer (score 0):

Generate a local ssh key (ssh-keygen, hit enter 3 times) and then copy ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys2 file on the target server, under the desired user. That's about the only way i can think of to do it. Once you have authenticated, make sure that whatever user you're using on the remote server has access to those files.

Comment: To clarify.  when you talk about "if they were created by root",  you are talking about .ssh and .ssh/authorized_keys2, right?  It cannot be a problem with the permissions of the files in /var/www as he's not yet authenticated.

Comment: I'm actually referring to the files he is trying to copy. If the user who created the files set them as read only for only his user/group, then if he is logging in as any other user they'll be unable to copy them due to lack of privs.

Comment: Then no, not possible.  He hasn't gotten past ssh authentication yet, so the permissions of those files cannot be the cause of this problem.

Comment: Ah re-reading it I see what you mean, for some reason i missed the part about the permission denied being from the login attempt. Will edit my answer.